On a particular uniform convergence
Let's consider a function $\phi(x)$ that we call "fairly good", meaning that $\phi(x)$ and all its derivatives of all orders are $O(|x|^N)$, for $|x|\to\infty$, with $N\in\mathbb{N}$ known.
Let's consider then the integral:
$$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-t)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x-t)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
where $\delta_n(y)=\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}}e^{-ny^2}$ (or, if it could be useful in any way, its equivalent form with compact support $ \delta_n(y)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{1-\left(ny\right)^2}}}{\int_{u=-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-\left(nu\right)^2}}\mathrm{d} u}\chi_{\left[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right]}\left(x\right) $).
My question is: is the convergence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ uniform with respect to $t$, given the hypothesis on $\phi(x)$?
The answer I am slowly becoming convinced of is no, because essentially the derivatives of $\phi$ can still be unbounded. This limitation is in fact what I would have needed in this proof attempt of mine:
$$\left|\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x-t)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x-\phi(t)\right|=\left|\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x-t)(\phi(x)-\phi(t))\mathrm{d}x\right|\leq \\ \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x-t)|\phi(x)-\phi(t)|\mathrm{d}x\leq \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x-t)\cdot|\phi'(\xi)|\cdot|x-t|\mathrm{d}x$$
where $\xi$ is a suitable point in the open interval delimited by $x$ and $t$. At this point I would really like to say that $|\phi'(\xi)|$ is less than $ \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}|\phi'(y)| $ to make everything independent from $t$ and finish, but I can't.
I don't think the problem can be solved in any way if I don't add the hypothesis of the boundedness of the derivatives on $\phi$, is that correct?
Thanks in advance.
PS: the problem isn't solved even if I use the $\delta_n$ version with compact support. In that case, in fact, I can certainly legally apply the inequality with $\sup_{y\in (t-1/n,t+1/n)}|\phi'(y)|$, but everything would still depend from $t$ and I would not arrive at uniform convergence.

A counterexample is obtained by taking $\phi(x) = x \sin(x)$. Use for example the compactly supported form of $\delta_n$. Now look at what happens for $t_n = 2 \pi n^2 + \pi/2$. We have $\phi(t_n) = t_n$ so the interesting quantity is
$$\Delta_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x-t_n)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x - \phi(t_n) = \int_{t_n-1/n}^{t_n+1/n} \delta_n(x-t_n)(\phi(x)-t_n)\mathrm{d}x.$$
If your function converges uniformly with respect to $t$, then $\Delta_n$ must converge to 0. We prove it isn't the case:
Using the change of variables y = x- t_n, since $\sin (y + 2 \pi n^2 + \pi/2) = \cos(y) $, we get
$$\Delta_n = \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} \delta_n(y)((t_n + y)\cos(y) - t_n)\mathrm{d}y.$$
Using that $y \mapsto y \cos(y)$ is odd, we get $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}  y \cos(y) = 0$ so
$$\Delta_n = \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} \delta_n(y)(t_n \cos(y) - t_n)\mathrm{d}y = t_n \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} \delta_n(y)( \cos(y) - 1)\mathrm{d}y$$
Now use for $y \sim 0$, $\cos(y) = 1 - \frac{y^2} 2 + o(y^2) \le 1 - \frac{y^2} 4$ to get ($\Delta_n \le 0$ because $\cos(y) \le 1$)
$$\Delta_n\le - t_n \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} \delta_n(y)\frac{y^2} 4\mathrm{d}y = -2 t_n \int_{0}^{1/n} \delta_n(y)\frac{y^2} 4\mathrm{d}y $$
$$ |\Delta_n | \ge 2 t_n \int_{0}^{1/n}\delta_n(y)\frac{y^2} 4\mathrm{d}y \ge 2 t_n \int_{1/2n}^{1/n}\delta_n(y)\frac{1}{4(2n)^2}\mathrm{d}y = \frac {t_n} {8 n^2} \int_{1/2n}^{1/n}\delta_n(y)\mathrm{d}y.$$
Using the change of variable $z= ny$, one can see that $\int_{1/2n}^{1/n}\delta_n(y)\mathrm{d}y$ is independant on $n$ so $\Delta_n$ scales like $t_n / n^2$ but $t_n \sim 2\pi n^2$ hence $|\Delta_n| $ is lower bounded by a strictly positive constant, contradicting the fact that it must converge to 0. So we have a counterexample.
